# How to get the site name of a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, url

I made an OData Controller in a ASP.NET application and call its methods like this(e.g. from fiddler):

**Local Version:**

```
http://localhost:2343/api/SWD/GetMyEntities
<-----baseUrl-------><----static part----->
```

**Server Version**

```
http://myServer/myApp/api/SWD/GetMyEntities
<-----baseUrl-------><----static part----->
```

I know how to make the `baseUrl` for the local version in Silverlight. Here is the code:

```
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}",
                       Application.Current.Host.Source.Schema,
                       Application.Current.Host.Source.Host,
                       Application.Current.Host.Source.Port);

string methodUrl = baseUrl +"/api/SWD/GetMyEntities";
```

But for the Server Version this code returns:

```
http://myServer/api/SWD/GetMyEntities
```

So where is the site name (`myApp`)? Is there any function to find out the site's name in the IIS (which is provided when publishing the application to IIS)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you could use:

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

or

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the computer name. When we publish the project to IIS, It ask for `Site Name` and here I'm looking for that.

Comment: Ok, so in your example you want to get "myApp"?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that, is there any best practice?